# Inequality with 6 variables

Tags: inequality

I am trying to show the following,

Let, $x,y,z,a,b,c$ be positive reals such that $x+y+z=1$

Then $ax + by + cz +2 \sqrt{(ab+bc+ca)(xy+yz+zx)} \leq a+b+c$

This is practice problem 6 in [this](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/MildorfInequalities.pdf) document

This is equivalent to

$\sqrt{(ab+bc+ca)(xy+yz+zx)} \leq \frac{(y+z)a+(x+z)b+(x+y)c}{2(x+y+z)}$

But I am not avle to apply Jensen's inequality. Thank you for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since Use twice Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
\begin{align*}
&ax+by+cz+2\sqrt{(ab+bc+ac)(xy+yz+xz)}\\
&\le\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}
+\sqrt{(2ab+2bc+2ac)(2xy+2yz+2xz)}\\
&\le \sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac)(x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2yz+2xz)}\\
&=(a+b+c)(x+y+z)\\
&=a+b+c
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much. Is the second term$(x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2yz+2xz)$

Answer (score 1):

Apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$ab+bc+ca \leq \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}$,

$xy+yz+zx \leq \dfrac{(x+y+z)^2}{3}$.

Thus: $LHS \leq ax+by+cz +\dfrac{2(a+b+c)(x+y+z)}{3} \leq x+y+z \iff 2(ax+by+cz) \leq a(y+z)+b(x+z)+c(x+y) \iff 3(ax+by+cz) \leq a+b+c \iff px+qy+rz \leq \dfrac{1}{3}, p+q+r=1, p = \dfrac{a}{a+b+c}, q = \dfrac{b}{a+b+c}, r = \dfrac{c}{a+b+c}$.

At this point, if you are okay with Lagrange Multiplier, then you are just "right there" at the answer, namely: Let $f(x,y,z) = px+qy+rz$, with $p+q+r = 1 = x+y+z$.

$f_x = \lambda = f_y =f_z \Rightarrow p = q = r = \dfrac{1}{3} \to f \leq \dfrac{1}{3}x+\dfrac{1}{3}y+\dfrac{1}{3}z = \dfrac{1}{3}(x+y+z) = \dfrac{1}{3}$.